# How to use Android Room to store data records

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, android-room, android-livedata

I want to store team information in an Android Room database. The information contains team name, players, batting, fielding, and bowling statistics.

These are my requirements:

- Team Names have to display in first recyclerview as a list
- When a user selects a team, the user will navigate to a team information screen that shows all players in the team
- If a user selects a player, the user will navigate to the player info screen that shows the player's information like bowling, batting, and Fielding statistics

Can anyone please give me suggestions to fulfill these requirements?

Comment: Hi @Venkat, welcome to Stackoverflow! You should post what you have up to now form the code and your attempts.

Comment: You can store a String JSON, but it's really necessary to store all information in just one column? wouldn't it be better to work with foreign key?

Comment: will you please explain how can i use the foreign key for different tables

Comment: Language cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to store team names & players into separate tables with its primary and foreign keys, respectively, in order to make relation between them. After all, if you need to fetch stored data, you can join tables, or get by team name (if it is primary key) or anything else.

You can read more about @Relation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation

Relation can help you handle one-to-many, many-to-many states.

Note: do all tasks in background thread with the help of Rx/Coroutines.